# Expand LaTeX macros to modify

Tags: macros, expansion, polynom

I am using the `polynom` package for polynomial long division. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polynom}

\begin{document}

\polylongdiv{x^3-x^2+d}{x-2}

\end{document}
```

Notice that I have another variable `d` there. `polynom` handles it well but calls it `1d`.

[image: screenshot]

Is there any way to expand the code so I can edit out the `1`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Like any latex package `polynom` is essentially a program whose source is available, so you can modify it:

Not extensively tested but...

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polynom}

\begin{document}

%\tracingall
\makeatletter
\def\pld@AccuPrint@#1#2{%
  \ifnum #2=\@ne \ifnum#1=\@ne\zz\else\number #1\fi\else \frac {\number #1}{\number #2}\fi }

\def\zz{\expandafter\zzz\romannumeral`\^^@}
\def\zzz{\futurelet\tmp\zzz@}
\def\zzz@{\ifx\tmp\let\else1\fi}

\polylongdiv{x^3-x^2+d}{x-2}

% check 1 is still printed if no following variable
\polylongdiv{x^3-x^2+1}{x-2}


%  Heiko
\polylongdiv{1+d}{1}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It will not work, if the result is `1+d`, then the `1` will also vanish.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek ah, it worked on the two I tested it with:-), if you know this code is it likely to be easy to fix? I'll have a quick look but delete the answer if I don't spot something obvious.

Comment: @FrankEpps see Heiko's comment above

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek better?

Comment: At least the few examples seems to work. My first try was in the same direction. But the test for `\pld@true`/`\let` as next token was not specific enough for me. Thus I patched at a higher level.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek OK thanks for the thoughts, I'll give you a vote but hopefully you won't steal my tick (again:-)

Comment: Thanks, but already red-capped. BTW, it is not "stealing". "Well deserved" is a better phrase, if a tick moves to me. :-))

Answer (score 11):

The final line is printed as

```
\pld@R {4}{1}+\pld@R {1}{1}\pld@S {d}{1}
```

`\pld@R` has the meaning of `\pld@Rational`. Thus the following example redefines `\pld@Rational`. If the numerator and denominator are equal and a symbol (`\pld@S`) follows, then `\pld@R{1}{1}` will omit the factor before the symbol.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polynom}

\makeatletter
\let\pldx@saved@PrintRational\pld@PrintRational
\renewcommand*{\pld@PrintRational}[2]{%
  \def\pldx@do{\pldx@PrintRational{#1}{#2}}%
  \futurelet\pldx@token\pldx@do
}
\newcommand*{\pldx@PrintRational}[2]{%
  \let\pldx@do\@firstofone
  \ifx\pldx@token\pld@S
    \def\pldx@a{#1}%
    \def\pldx@b{#2}%
    \ifx\pldx@a\pldx@b
      \let\pldx@do\@gobble
    \fi
  \fi
  \pldx@do{%
    \pldx@saved@PrintRational{#1}{#2}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

  \polylongdiv{x^3-x^2+d}{x-2}%

  \polylongdiv{x^3-x^2-3+d}{x-2}%

  % David Carlisle's test cases:

  \polylongdiv{x^3-x^2+1}{x-2}

  \polylongdiv{1+d}{1}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]