# Suppress coefficient 1 in polynomial

Tags: polynom

Is there a way to suppress the coefficient 1 in front of *a* in the following calculation?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polynom}

\begin{document}
    \[
        \polylongdiv{x^3 + ax^2 - x + 4}{x - 1}
    \]
\end{document}
```

[image: Output from polynom]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an old question and I think that your question it is a duplicate of this question: [Expand LaTeX macros to modify](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133983/expand-latex-macros-to-modify). I have used the excellent [macro](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133983/expand-latex-macros-to-modify) of the answer of Sep 18 '13 at 20:45 of the user @Heiko Oberdiek, for example, that delete the coefficient `1`. Or if you prefer work correctly also the macro of @David Carlisle. Here there is an example.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{polynom}

\makeatletter
\let\pldx@saved@PrintRational\pld@PrintRational
\renewcommand*{\pld@PrintRational}[2]{%
  \def\pldx@do{\pldx@PrintRational{#1}{#2}}%
  \futurelet\pldx@token\pldx@do
}
\newcommand*{\pldx@PrintRational}[2]{%
  \let\pldx@do\@firstofone
  \ifx\pldx@token\pld@S
    \def\pldx@a{#1}%
    \def\pldx@b{#2}%
    \ifx\pldx@a\pldx@b
      \let\pldx@do\@gobble
    \fi
  \fi
  \pldx@do{%
    \pldx@saved@PrintRational{#1}{#2}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\[\polylongdiv{x^3 + ax^2 - x + 4}{x - 1}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]